# Unable to View the output of a python Script in Powershell

Tags: python

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.readlines()
```

[image: output screen shot]`

When I type these lines in my Powershell, I get no syntax error. But the *print* statement shows no output. Am I missing something?

Also attached a screenshot for reference.

Comment: where is the print statement.

Comment: please refer the screen shot

Comment: press Enter again - you haven't got back to the `>>` prompt so it's still waiting for more lines of Python. It does work: http://i.imgur.com/HGmR7yV.png   (Or maybe your file is an enormous multi-gigabyte thing and it's taking forever to build an in-memory array?)

Comment: Thanks man! it worked, i have to reach till >> to execute the program?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have press `enter` to get prompt `>>` then it will show you the output